# Java 8 LocalDateTime today at specific hour

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Is there a nicer/easier way of constructing `LocalDateTime` object representing today at 6 AM than this?

```
LocalDateTime todayAt6 = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(6).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
```

Somehow I don't like dealing with minutes/seconds/nano when all I want to say is `now().withHours()`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`LocalDate` has various overloaded `atTime` methods, such as [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atTime-int-int-), which takes two arguments (hour of day and minute):

```
LocalDateTime todayAt6 = LocalDate.now().atTime(6, 0);
```

Answer (score 17):

Another alternative (specially if you want to change an already existing `LocalDateTime`) is to use the [`with()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-).

It accepts a `TemporalAdjuster` as a parameter. And according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-), passing a `LocalTime` to this method does exactly what you need:

> The classes LocalDate and LocalTime implement TemporalAdjuster, thus this method can be used to change the date, time or offset:
>
> result = localDateTime.with(date);
>      result = localDateTime.with(time);

So, the code will be:

```
LocalDateTime todayAt6 = LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.of(6, 0));
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to `LocalDate.now().atTime(6, 0)` is:

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).withHour(6);
```

Answer (score 8):

That works

```
LocalDateTime.now().withHour(3).withMinute(0).withSecond(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is a good one. You can also create your own [clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#tick-java.time.Clock-java.time.Duration-) to do this:

```
Clock clock = Clock.tick(Clock.systemDefaultZone(), Duration.ofHours(1));
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
```

This can be a useful option if used repeatedly, because the clock can be stored in a static variable:

```
public static final Clock CLOCK = Clock.tick(Clock.systemDefaultZone(), Duration.ofHours(1));
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now(CLOCK);
```